# How to access global variables in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to access a global variable that was set in my Global.asax section of my project. When include the namespace in my DAL and access the variable visual studio complains. Here is the code

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
     RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
     RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
     Application["NHSessionFactory"] = CreateSessionFactory();
}
```

And here is my DAL logic

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NHibernate;

namespace Data.DAL
{
    public class DB
    {
        private ISessionFactory session;
        public DB()
        {
            ISessionFactory session = (ISessionFactory) Application["NHSessionFactory"];   //problems here
        }

        public ISessionFactory GetSession()
        {
            return session;
        }
    }
}
```

A screen shot of the error:
[image]

How would I access that variable that was set in Global.asax?

Comment: How does it complain? What's the structure of the application (where is the DAL code relative to the application)

Comment: What error message are you getting ? Where is CreateSessionFactory defined? Could ot possibly be returning null?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the Application variables same way as asp.net

```
Example:

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["NHSessionFactory"] = "Something";
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.UnLock();
```